# Binding enum to combobox at win8 platform using mvvmlight

Tags: c#, combobox, enums, windows-8.1, mvvm-light

I'm trying to bind an enum to combobox, so I tried to follow a guide that suggested using this code:

```
    <Page.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider MethodName="GetValues"
    ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}"
    x:Key="ExampleEnumValues">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <x:Type TypeName="ExampleEnum" />
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
</Page.Resources>
```

The problem is that it says that "objectdataprovider is not supported in a windows app project".  is there another way to do it? Thanks to everyone in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you want the enum values showed in the combobox, all you have to do is this:

at your viewModel:

```
    public Array SomeName { get; set; }
//c'tor
 public viewModelName()
        {
            SomeName = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnumType));
        }
```

And at your view:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SomeName}" ></ComboBox>
```